# Finding Happy Numbers

Tags: java, for-loop, numbers, repeat

So, for my AP Computer Science class, we have to find all of the Happy Numbers and print them out at the end. I know I could have done this code a lot simpler, however, it made more sense to me this way. Here is my issue: In my for loop, it is only running the first number, if it is a happy number, it prints said number out, if it isn't it doesn't print anything, but it will not go to the next number at all. Thanks for your help! My code is below:

```
public class HappyNumbers
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        boolean done = false;
        int sum = 0;
        for (int x = 1; x < Integer.MAX_VALUE; x++)
        {
            String a = "" + x;

            while (!done)
            {
                int length = a.length();

                if (length == 1)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    sum = (int)Math.pow(b,2);
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;

                    if (y == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }

                }


                else if (length == 2)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (y == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;

                    }
                }

                else if (length == 3)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    sum =(int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (y == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (length == 4)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (length == 5)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (length == 6)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    int g = a.charAt(5) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2) + Math.pow(g,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (length == 7)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    int g = a.charAt(5) - '0';
                    int h = a.charAt(6) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2) + Math.pow(g,2) + Math.pow(h,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;

                    }
                }

                else if (length == 8)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    int g = a.charAt(5) - '0';
                    int h = a.charAt(6) - '0';
                    int i = a.charAt(7) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2) + Math.pow(g,2) + Math.pow(h,2) + Math.pow(i,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (length == 9)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    int g = a.charAt(5) - '0';
                    int h = a.charAt(6) - '0';
                    int i = a.charAt(7) - '0';
                    int j = a.charAt(8) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2) + Math.pow(g,2) + Math.pow(h,2) + Math.pow(i,2) + Math.pow(j,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;
                    }
                }

                else if (length == 10)
                {
                    int b = a.charAt(0) - '0';
                    int c = a.charAt(1) - '0';
                    int d = a.charAt(2) - '0';
                    int e = a.charAt(3) - '0';
                    int f = a.charAt(4) - '0';
                    int g = a.charAt(5) - '0';
                    int h = a.charAt(6) - '0';
                    int i = a.charAt(7) - '0';
                    int j = a.charAt(8) - '0';
                    int k = a.charAt(9) - '0';
                    sum = (int)(Math.pow(b,2) + Math.pow(c,2) + Math.pow(d,2) + Math.pow(e,2) + Math.pow(f,2) + Math.pow(g,2) + Math.pow(h,2) + Math.pow(i,2) + Math.pow(j,2) + Math.pow(k,2));
                    int y = (int)sum;
                    a = "" + y;
                    if (sum == 1)
                    {
                        System.out.println(x);
                        done = true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is probably getting stuck in your while loop. Have you tried debugging it, is done ever being set to true?

Comment: It gets stuck in the else if loops. So it is only printing or not printing the first number. How can I fix this?

Comment: else if statements are not loops and your code cannot get stuck in them. Is it getting stuck in your while loop? I would suggest you step through it and figure out what's happening.

Comment: They were getting stuck there because if it never hit sum == 1, it would continue to run.  So there were stuck in the while loop, but inside the else if loops.Thanks for your help though. I was able to fix the code before it was due. Thanks.

Comment: I added another if statement under the done == true; in each loop. The if statement I added was the numbers that make it a cycle, which would make it "unhappy." If it hit one of these numbers, done = false; underneath the done == false; I added a break;   With this addition, the code works completely

Comment: Adding a break is the logical equivalent of setting done to true. Which says that your while loop is probably completely unnecessary, why did you put the while loop there in the first place?

Comment: Okay. If I did not have the while loop, it only would have done the sum of each digit squared once. With the while loop, it continuously went until it hit 1

Answer (score 0):

beacause you set

```
done = true;
```

in line 25

Comment: That might be the problem, but it is not a full solution. What exactly is needed to fix the program? Would it work if line 25 is removed?